# Cannot access individual elements with this.$refs in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this

I have a strange problem. wanted to access some elements in the created() hook. Specifically:
this i have accesss to the refs object:

```js
    created() {
      console.log(this.$refs)
    }

    // returns:
    {
      bar: div.red.bar
      content: div.name-description
      description: p.description.dark
      redContainer: div.red.red-container
      sections: div.sections
      title: h1.name.dark
      __proto__: Object
    }
```

But when i try to target a specific element I end up with undefined:

```js
created() {
    console.log(this.$refs.content)
  }
  
//returns

undefined
```

Does anybody know why I have this behavior?
Similar problems when trying to get the width / height from elements in computed properties...
(e.g. this.$refs.content.clientWidth)

Comment: Common issue in JavaScript, you cannot rely on `console.log()` to output properties of an object, as these properties are not always available at the time the output is generated.  see https://forum.vuejs.org/t/accessing-refs/15049 for example, but this is a common JavaScript issue; see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=console.log+properties+undefined for many examples of similar questions.

Comment: in Vue specifically, the properties of `$refs` will be `undefined` until the `mounted()` lifecycle event;  Unfortunately, I believe this would mean you can't access `$refs` in the `created()` hook.  This actually makes sense, because the DOM is actually built in between `created()` and `mounted()`, and so DOM elements wouldn't exist yet in `created()`.  see https://blog.logrocket.com/introduction-to-vue-lifecycle-hooks/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access refs from the `created` hook because the child components/elements have not been instantiated yet; instead access from the `mounted` hook:

```js
Vue.component('foo', {
  template: '<div>foo</div>',
  created() {
    console.log('foo created')
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created() {
    console.log('parent created: $refs.foo is null?', this.$refs.foo == null)
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('parent mounted: $refs.foo is null?', this.$refs.foo == null)
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <foo ref="foo"></foo>
</div>
```

The reason why you're getting a discrepancy between the `console.log` output showing that the components are there but when you access one of the components it's not is probably because the browser is evaluating the properties of `this.$refs` lazily only once you click the arrow to expand the properties of the object, and by the time it is evaluated the child components have been created.

Answer (score 0):

`this.$refs` is an object type, when your output is created, it will get a value undefined, then it will get another value of object type in mounted, and both values have the same reference in memory, either changed, another will change.